# MarkLogic how can I constrain my graph query through REST service or JAVA api

Tags: jena, marklogic, marklogic-8

```html
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sem:triples xmlns:sem="http://marklogic.com/semantics">
  <start-time xmlns="http://abc.com.au/meta#">2016-12-08T17:19:59.220366+11:00</start-time>
  <stop-time xmlns="http://abc.com.au/meta#">2999-12-31T00:00:00+11:00</stop-time>
  <sem:triple>
    <sem:subject>http://abc.au/abc/abc/Model#abc</sem:subject>
    <sem:predicate>http://abc.com.au/core/abc#minOccurs</sem:predicate>
    <sem:object datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">0</sem:object>
  </sem:triple>
</sem:triples>
```

MarkLogic provides a Java API to load a semantic graph using its URI. The API sends an HTTP request to MarkLogic to retrieve the graph. However, at the moment the request parameters only include a graph URI but nothing else. We would like to constrain our graph loading by some range constraints. We are using [embedded triples](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/embedded#chapter) in MarkLogic with some additional timestamps identifying the version of triples. Is there a way for us to specify the timestamps as range constraints in an HTTP request when we load the graph through REST service? We only need to load part of the graph that matches the timestamp constraint.

The reason we want to load triples as a graph is because we want to use it with Apache Jena. In order to execute SPARQL using Jena, we first need to load the graph as a RDF model into Jena's query engine.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-jena? And which of these REST endpoints: http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/graphs? Some of those accept a structured query parameter, that would work against the documents in which those triples are embedded..

Comment: Your scenario sounds very interesting, and I thin the answer is "yes you can do that" but I don't understand completely.  Can you paste a document with embedded triples?  If you store such a document in MarkLogic, Jena can query the triples therein no problem.

Comment: @grtjn yes I am using that wrapper. The problem with that wrapper is that every time you call "toDataset()" method in order to start a sparql query, it just calls the marklogic java api to load the whole graph and loads the graph into Jena such that the sparql query can be executed against the model. I have dived into the marklogic java api and I know it is calling the "/V1/graphs" end point. However this end point seems to not support specifying additional query parameters apart from the graph URI. I would like to constrain the loading of the triples of the graph by specifying a time range.

Comment: @grechaw I uploaded an example document where you can see there is a start time and end time. In Marklogic we use ctx functions to constrain the time range by consulting with those two parameters when executing a sparql query. In Jena, before executing a sparql query, we want to load the graph model from Marklogic first. So in Marklogic's Java client apis, do we have a means to load a graph which only has triples that match the time range we specify? At the moment, when I call "MarklogicDatasetGraph.toDataset().getDefaultModel()" it returns me a whole graph regardless the timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than loading the default graph into the client, you'll want to use the `setConstrainingQuery()` method on `SPARQLQueryDefinition`.

Assuming you have a range index on element `{"http://abc.com.au/meta#}start-time` of type dateTime, then you can do this:

```
SPARQLQueryManager sparqlQueryManager;

StructuredQueryBuilder qb = new StructuredQueryBuilder();
StructuredQueryDefinition structuredQuery = qb.and(
   qb.range(qb.element(new QName("http://abc.com.au/meta#", "start-time")), EvalResult.Type.DATETIME, StructuredQueryBuilder.Operator.GE, value),
   qb.range(qb.element(new QName("http://abc.com.au/meta#", "end-time")), EvalResult.Type.DATETIME, StructuredQueryBuilder.Operator.LE, value));
SPARQLQueryDefinition sparql = sparqlQueryManager.newQueryDefinition("select ...");
sparql.setConstrainingQueryDefinition(structuredQuery);
JsonNode results = sparqlQueryManager.executeSelect(sparql, new JacksonHandle()).get();
```

However, it looks like you might be trying to do something with temporality -- the MarkLogic bitemporal feature takes care of some of the hard things you run into with temporal databases.